# C# winforms, storing value from numericupdown

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port, numericupdown

I have a serialport dataRecived event with 2 methods inside it. The LogFile is loging data and drawSetpoint is drawing a graph.

```
public void serialPort1_DataRecived  (object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {

            DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
            string Rdata = serialPort1.ReadLine();
            LogFile(Rdata, (int)numericSetpoint.Value);
            drawSetpoint(time,numericSetpoint.Value.ToString());


        }
```

Both methods take the second argument from a numericUpDown control which looks like this

```
public void numericSetpoint_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == 13) 
            {

                if (serialPort1.IsOpen) 
                {
                    int setpoint = (int)numericSetpoint.Value;
                    //send to serial port .....                    
                }
```

The problem is both methods in my data recived event read digits as I type them. For example, if I type 150, LogFile will show 1,15,150 and the draw function will start drawing 1,15,150. I would like both functions to take the value from the numericSetpoint control after the enter key is pressed so i get the whole value. How could I do that ?

Comment: The Keypress event is working fine. The problem is reading the Value with those 2 functions inside the dataRecived event. They read the value immediately when i start typing which is why they show 1,15,150. I would like to read the whole value at once after enter is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the KeyPress event.  Instead consider using the ValueChanged event which only fires when enter is pressed or the user leaves the control https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.valuechanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Hm, the ValueChanged event fires as soon as i start typing, i don't even need to press enter to send the value.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your data rx event is firing while your typing. I would try filling a buffer in your data rx event and hold off on any logging or plotting until you've sent your data. There are bunch of "safe" ways to do this but the core logic is as follows:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[MAX_BUFFER];
private volatile bool _ready = false;
private Object _lock = new Object();

public void serialPort1_DataRecived  (object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{

    DateTime time = DateTime.Now;

    // Either read as bytes or convert string to bytes, add to your buffer
    // string Rdata = serialPort1.ReadLine();

    lock(_lock )
    {
        if(_ready)
        {
            _ready = false;
            var myData = your buffer as string
            // clear buffer
            LogFile(myData, (int)numericSetpoint.Value);
            drawSetpoint(time,numericSetpoint.Value.ToString());
        }
    }

}

...

public void numericSetpoint_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == 13) 
    {

        if (serialPort1.IsOpen) 
        {
            int setpoint = (int)numericSetpoint.Value;
            //send to serial port .....     
            lock(_lock ) { _ready = true; }               
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, i'll try it and report back. I've never used the lock before, since i'm receving data every 100 ms from my arduino will the lock affect my graph (chart)?

Comment: i'm getting "'bool' is not a reference type as required by the lock statement" error.

Comment: Sorry, I've update the example to be more clear. Make an object and lock on that. All this does is prevent a race condition on the _ready flag. For testing you could probably omit it.

Comment: I'm stuck on the buffer part. Could i use a List<string> as a buffer and if so how? Since i already read a string from serialport and LogFile is taking a string as a parameter, feels like conversion to bytes would complicate things.

Comment: You can do whatever you want :) Byte arrays are traditionally used and I've never found them to introduce complexities. Try it with the string list and if that is resolving your issue, then you weight the complexity of using a byte array buffer instead.